# Looking for a program which uses LZW compression

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, compression

I need to learn how to do [Lempel–Ziv–Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZW) compression using pen and paper for my algorithms and data structures class. Unfortunately we have only a couple of examples in our book of how it is done. I'd like to practice compressing and decompressing text using it, but I need to find a way to check if I'm right doing it right or wrong.

So I'm looking for some preferably free/open source program which can compress and decompress LZW for Windows or GNU/Linux. Programs without binary distributions are fine too.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch)?

Comment: @David Zaslavsky Yes, I linked Wikipedia article in my original question. Why? The section where software which uses it is mentioned is a bit vague.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't paying quite enough attention when I read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `ncompress` package.

Comment: Looks promising. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

GIF compression is LZW, any GIF library will have code for it.

http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/2d/GIF-comp.txt